# Number of concurrent tasks run in AWS managed Airflow is not linearly dependant on the number of Workers

Tags: python, airflow, mwaa

AWS provides to run Airflow as a service. It has 3 different environments in which it can be run, namely Small, Medium and Large. These environments have different configurations of CPU and RAM. I used the Large config which has 4vCPUs and 8GB RAM (for each worker) which allows 20 concurrent tasks to be run by default (by each worker). I was able to run around 40 tasks in parallel with 1 worker(Min. worker = 1, Max Worker = 1, Scheduler =2)(each task was of a different dag run). When I run more than 40 tasks I find that the latency of the task increases significantly.
So when I increase the number of workers the number of tasks I am able to run should be a multiplication of the tasks by one worker and number of workers, but with 25workers( I was only able to run around 260 tasks. When I go beyond this value the latency increases.

I am trying to figure out what other config changes can be tweaked to increase the performance and reduce latency. Please let me know if you need more details.

I've attached the screenshot of my config.

[Airflow Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L39MI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the max number of schedulers that AWS can maintain feasibly is 5. The number of tasks airflow could pick was more dependant on the schedulers in my use case since the tasks were not compute intensive. So the number of schedulers needed to schedule the tasks were more critical as the tasks were completed quickly and idle workers to take up next tasks were available. Since the max number of schedulers is 5, this is the max airflow can do for my use case and hence not suitable for my application.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended number of workers on a large node is 20. If you increase the number of tasks, the performance will degrade as tasks are computing for CPU. Also each task is forked in its own process and needs memory, which can cause OOM errors eventually.

One solution to run more tasks in parallel is to let aws airflow "autoscale" your airflow cluster by adding more node. To do so you would set the "Max Worker" config to 2 or more.

More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-autoscaling.html)

Comment: Even if I have 20 workers where each worker can run 20 tasks which gives 400 tasks that can be run in whole. But I find significant latency in the running tasks even for 300 concurrent tasks. My actual question is that each worker is given a "node" and each large node has 8GB of RAM and 4vCPUs. So when I'm increasing the workers the CPU available for each worker is still the same. So if one worker can do 20 tasks minimum 20 workers should be able to do 400 tasks Comfortably, but that isn't the case. I'm trying to debug the reason for this.

Comment: With your settings, you are running 40 tasks on 4 workers CPU, so if your tasks are CPU intensive they are going to slow down as soon as 4 tasks are running in parallel.

Comment: No. I said I am able to run 40 tasks with 1 worker. Refer the information under Environment Class for understanding: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/environment-class.html) .
So if 1 worker can ru 40 tasks, more workers should run tasks equivalent to the multiple of the number of workers.